# How do I distribute my slightly customized Linux in VirtualBox?

Tags: installation, virtualization, distribution, virtualbox

Suppose I've got some Arch Linux installation which I'd like to distribute among students with (sometimes very) basic Linux knowledge to make them able to compile C programs in an environment very similar to that in the university. (Things like Cygwin or MinGW seem to be inappropriate here.)

I also choose VirtualBox as a holder for the virtual system.

The question is: **how do I distribute it**? I mean:

- installing VirtualBox on the target machine (if not still installed)
- uncompressing and copying my image file (.VDI)
- registering the image (so that VirtualBox could see it when launched)
- configuring the guest system in VirtualBox (network, memory, etc.)
- optionally installing PuTTY to simplify interfacing with the guest Linux

Should I create an installer? Which one? Or just write some .BAT-scripts? (Target host system is Windows, mostly XP and Vista.) I definately don't want to have a webpage with screen shot explaining where to click and what to press, because it's boring.

---

Additionaly, what will be the best (the most user-friendly) way to configure network when the guest Linux system is run for the first time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did that once this way:

1. I burned a DVD containig: VirtualBox & the image
2. I wrote an autostart.exe that: Installed VirtualBox and Putty on the Machine
3. It copied the image to the HD
4. Then the autostart.exe ran the Virtualbox configuration and added the virtual machine
5. Then the virtual machine was started and an auto starting bash script showed the virtual machine's network information, telling the students how to connect via Putty.
6. That's it

Also: Include a panic function on the DVD: A simple script that removes the virtual machine's image from the hd and copies the original one from the dvd to the hd. This really saves a LOT of time.